# findstr command without the new line (the Enter keys)

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I need to use findstr command without new line.

My file "prova.txt" contains:

```
La#
Do#
Fa#
```

My batch file contains:

```
@echo off
FINDSTR Do# prova.txt
```

The result of command is:

```
Do#
//second empty line
```

Instead I wish it was:

```
Do#
```

How do I get this?

I Explain better:

I don't want the new line (the Enter keys) after the findstr command.

Comment: You mean you do not want the trailing new-line?

Comment: *every* command (nearly) gives you a trailing empty line. Do you have a special problem with it? You *could* write a script for output without that empty line, but I doubt, it is worth it, execpt you have a special need for it.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Whats the finallity of your code ?

Comment: There isn't a magical, _(unless you use the appropriate shell)_, echo -n solution. The long winded NT command script solution would require a real task with real strings and a genuine end product.

Comment: exactly @aschipfl

Comment: @SachaDee I don't want the new line (the Enter keys) after the findstr command.

Comment: @Stephan, in general you are right in your comment, except for the terminology: a trailing new-line (or end-of line) marker is not an empty line; you have got an empty line only when there are no characters between a previous new-line (or the beginning of a string/file) and the next one; so to have got an empty line at the end of a string/file you need to have two consecutive new-lines at the end...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't anderstand what you're trying to do. But try like this :

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('FINDSTR "Do#" "prova.txt"') do echo|set /p="%%a"
echo.
```

Comment: I think, you're ruining the effect by writing an CRLF afterwards `:D`

Comment: @Stephan Did you try it ? If you don't put one the output is : `Do#C:\Users\pc\Desktop>` thats why I putted a echo. after.....

Comment: actually, yes I did. By the way: works only, if there is no more than one match.

Comment: @SachaDee It's not unclear, it shows clearly that I don't want the new line (the Enter keys) after the findstr command. What's unclear?